# different number when converting number with numfmt back and forth

Tags: bash, docker

My initial goal was to compute size of all docker images. So I've end up with this one liner:

```
docker images | awk '{if(NR>1){print $NF}}' | tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]' | xargs numfmt --from=si --suffix=B | awk 'BEGIN {sum=0} {sum=sum+$1} END {print sum}' | numfmt --to=si --suffix=B
```

But after this I've realized that `numfmt` do some rounding or something weird during conversion

```
wakatana@ubuntu:~/$ echo 1.18GB | numfmt --from=si --suffix=B | numfmt --to=si --suffix=B
1.2GB
wakatana@ubuntu:~/$ echo 1.18GB | numfmt --from=iec --suffix=B | numfmt --to=iec --suffix=B
1.2GB
```

After this from/to conversion I am expecting same value as in beginning 1.18GB not 1.2GB. What I'm doing wrong

Answer (score 1):

The difference between `1.18GB` and `1.2GB` is caused by a rounding issue;

[image]

The default `from-zero` caused the output to be rounded to a single decimal.

Use [@Henry](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65477963/5625547) suggestion to format the number to 2 decimals using `--format %.2f`, then use `--round=nearest` to ensure rounding doesn't go up;

```sh
echo 1.18GB | numfmt --from=iec --suffix=B | numfmt --to=iec --suffix=B --format %.2f --round=nearest
1.18GB
```

---

If the rounding is not reliable enough, you could use [numfmt](/questions/tagged/numfmt) to get the number of bytes, and use a tool like [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) to convert back to `GB`;

```sh
echo 1.18GB | numfmt --from=iec --suffix=B | awk '{$1=$1/(1024*1024*1024); print $1,"GB";}'
1.18GB
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a format:

```
echo 1.18GB | numfmt --from=iec --suffix=B | numfmt --to=iec --format %.2f --suffix=B
```

This will still not give exactly 1.18GB but 1.19GB. This seems to be caused by some rounding errors.

Comment: Using `--format %.3f` will give `1.181GB` as result.